# Weird autocompletion when writing a decimal number in helm-mode

Tags: helm, prelude, ein

I am using [Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) with [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) activated. While using [Emacs IPython Notebook](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook) and `julia-mode`, I get an annoying auto-complete buffer pop up, when I am trying to type a decimal number, see figure below. how to stop this weird behavior?

[image]